# Accessing windows registry Python

Tags: python, windows, registry

I am stuck here trying to make a python script to access windows registry. My issue is that I get an error file not found using the following path:

> "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Signatures\Unmanaged"

It works until NetworkList and afterwards it just returns the error of file not found. I tried using different folders in the directory NetworkList but it gives error file not found for any of them. Using ragedit I can see that the directories that I am trying to access do exist. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it be deleting python 32 bit and installing python 64 bit, works like a charm

Comment: For a 32-bit process, `HKLM\SOFTWARE` gets redirected to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node`. You can set an access flag to instead use the 64-bit keys: e.g. `key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE', access=winreg.KEY_READ|winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY)`.